# Macbook wakes up at 1am

Tags: macbook-pro, sleep-wake

My Macbook pro has been in sleep with open lid and power. It suddenly waked up at 1am midnight. Screen is off actually. But fan started making loud noise, which made me believe it's up. After I closed the lid and unplugged power, fan noise stopped. What is happening here?

It's on Mojave.

Answer (score 1):

In SystemPreferences->Energy Saver->PowerAdapter:
uncheck "put harddisks to sleep when possible" (this is/was meant for HDD not SSD)
uncheck "Wake for network access" !!

in "schedule..." bottom right side: uncheck the two possibilities.
Restart after that to be sure.
That should do it.